# kafka producer and broker in different servers

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

My problem is:  how can I send data from a kafka producer to broker?
the schema below explains my network configuration :

[image]

I have a producer in VM which is located in server A, and my broker too is in VM which is located in Server B.

I use an `SSH` connection from my producer VM to the server B with a redirection port :  ssh -L 9092:192.168.56.101:9092 xx@IP1

I use kafka console to test :

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test
```

thanks

Comment: You are not asking a question. What is the problem? Any error message?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the --broker-list to wherever the broker resides.  In your code, you are saying that I want to produce a message and send it to a broker that is on the localhost machine at port 9092.  Try
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list 192.168.56.101:9092 --topic test

Comment: thanks, but 192.168.56.101 is not routable on the producer server.

Comment: @A.GARMES You need to open a network tunnel from your server A to server B for port 9092. And then the above solution will work.

Comment: @Kumar that is what he does with ssh, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @Harald Sorry! My bad.